# Where is EventLog coming from, why is it wrong?

Tags: logstash, nxlog

I have Windows eventlogs being sent from nxlog to logstash.  My windows box and my receiving server is in UTC.

NXlog appears to be adding EventTime to the log it ships, and the datetime is 7 hours behind UTC.  No explaination, I'm not setting it, and it doesn't match the timezone of either of my VM's or my host VM.

What is this EventTime?  Is NXLog creating it?  How come it has the wrong timezone or date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EventTime* stores the value of *TimeCreated* in case of im_msvistalog. When *EventTime* is converted to a string (e.g. by *to_json()*) it will be shown in local time.